# How do I initialize a custom view that is presented by UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, storyboard

I designed my code following the CoreDataBooks example from the iOS Developer Library. When pushing the +-Button in the UINavigationControl a segue to the custom AddViewController should appear, similar to the view in the iOS AddressBook.

I use a custom view controller instead of a UITableView controller, as in CoreDataBooks. So the code to present the view controller in CoreDataBooks looks like this:

```
AddViewController *addViewController = [[AddViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
addViewController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addViewController];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

and mine looks like this:

```
AddViewController *addViewController = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
[addViewController setDelegate: self];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addViewController];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

So it's basically the same, but I initialize the AddViewController with init and *not* with the initWithStyle method inherited by UITableViewController.

How do I correctly initialize my custom view controller? I tried to call [super init] in the init method, but this didn't help.

Comment: Can you post your `init` method from AddViewController?

Comment: Initially there was no init method. I tried to write one and just call the init of the super class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know when which initialization methods are called. If there is any good resource about this topic (especially with StoryBoards) I would be thankful.

Comment: If you're using storyboards is there a reason you allocating the view controller manually?

Comment: Well, I was following the code example, which looks nice except of this issue. An alternative would be to make the controller in StoryBoards. But if I know what init method to call it should work fine.

Comment: The problem is that CoreDataBooks doesn't use Storyboards, so following the example won't really work. Storyboards introduced a whole new way of performing transitions (segues) between view controllers.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's the best solution to make a segue with Storyboards. My personal preference is to do it manually because I like to know whats going on, but now I already spend too much time on this issue.

Comment: Don't give up. There's probably a simple answer to this problem. What class does your AddViewController inherit from? What are the contents of your AddViewController's -loadView and -viewDidLoad methods?

Comment: AddViewCOntroller inherits from DetailViewController which inherits from UIViewController. In the -viewDidLoad methods of the AddVIewController and the DetailViewController the contents are configures, but not initialized. I did not overwrite the -loadView methods, this seems to be a good thing to look after. Thanks!

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113388/creating-a-programmatic-tab-bar-with-storyboard-view-controllers) seems to be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using Storyboards to design the application flow, you should define the modal presentation as a modal segue in your storyboard, give the segue an identifier and override `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your root view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueIdentifier"]) {

        AddViewController *destination = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [destination setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I am aware of the possibility to create the view in Storyboards. However, I'd like to do it from code. If I knew which init method is called from the Storyboard I could call the same method from code and my problem would be solved.

Comment: ..TIL that you should not try to instantiate any view from code if you use storyboards.